# Unknown email adress logged into my Gmail.

Tags: gmail, google-account

An unknow account has logged in to my gmail or in my google apps. All his mails are coming to my gmail.How can i delete that account from my device as i dont know the password as it is an unknown account to me? Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an account can not login to another account. Though, you can have multiple accounts logged in into a single app.

Now about your question, if an account is logged in somehow into your gmail app, which you don't recognize, simply log out from that account and you are done.

To logout from gmail android app:

- Open up gmail app
- Click on the sidebar icon on top
- Click on the dropdown (⏷) icon in front of your account name/email
- Click on **Manage Accounts**
- From **Accounts & Sync**, select **Google**
- Select the account you want to remove from the list
- Click on the three dots icon on top and select **Remove Account** from there.
- The account will be removed and you won't get any emails anymore.

Just remember, it will also logout that account from all of the other applications. But as in your case, you don't recognize this account, it should be fine. 
Hope if helps!

Comment: If the above doesn't work, check to see if the emails are actually just being auto-forwarded to your account.

Answer (score 0):

I cant understand properly that has someone's Gmail account logged in your Gmail account or app..
or in your Computer.  So I am Answering for All the points...:)

If unknown gmail has added up in your computer then simply signout from  that mail..

Same if logged in your Gmail app sign-out that.
You have no need of password for logout from the Gmail.

But that Gmail account Collaborated with your Gmail account then means open with with gmail then simply goto settings of gmail then Accounts And Import and remove that unknown Gmail address and save.

But if someone hacks your mail then open the link from the login notification email and follow steps or go to account and privacy.